# How to use layouts from a folder in nuxtjs 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am developing an app using NuxtJs 3. In nuxt 3, layout feature has been changed. We can use layout via `<NuxtLayout name="layoutName">` and this `layoutName` is in layouts folder. My problem is,layout is in another folder inside layouts directory. How can i use that?

Comment: Can you try adding the foldername before the layoutName? like: `<NuxtLayout name="MyFolderLayoutName">`

Comment: @wittgenstein didn't get you. can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry. It didn't work that way. Thought it would because components can be imported like that.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure to fully understand what you want to have at the end, but let's say that you want to change the path of the `layouts` directory with the [`dir` property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-dir).

You can do that with the following in `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  dir: {
    layouts: 'fancyLayouts/nested'
  }
})
```

Then, all of your layouts will be available in that directory

[image]

Now, we have a very simple `other.vue` layout with the following (`custom.vue` is almost the same)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
    <br/>
    <p>other layout</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

We could have the following in `/pages/index.vue`

```html
<script>
definePageMeta({
  layout: false,
});
export default {
  data: () => ({
    layout: "custom",
  }),
};
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLayout :name="layout">
    <button class="border p-1 rounded" @click="layout === 'other' ? layout = 'custom' : layout = 'other'">
      Switch layout
    </button>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

This will allow us simply switch from one layout to another successfully aka `custom` or `other`.

[image]

---

If what you want is to have 2 directories like:

- `/layouts/custom.vue`
- `/layouts/nested/other.vue` (nested 1 level more)

Then, I did not achieved to have a simple way of managing the import regarding a **layout**.

I've never seen this kind of configuration and I'd even say that if you have a lot of various layouts (to the point of nesting them), then I recommend wrapping your content inside of **components** rather than **layouts** anyway.

Because layouts are meant to be quite simple global outside wrappers for the pages, nothing regarding a complex structure. It's more of a component's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added in Nuxt 2 long ago.

[Adds support for folders in /layouts #1865](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/1865)

[Nuxt.js does not respect layouts in separate folders. #1854](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1854)

It does not seem to work the same way in nuxt 3 because I'm facing the same issue.

[Layouts inside folders Nuxt js 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917821/layouts-inside-folders-nuxt-js-3)

*update...*

I checked the source code for Nuxt 3 and definitely is not supported what you are trying to do.

example: `layouts/folder/custom.vue`

and then use it in pages like follows

`<NuxtLayout name="folder/custom">some code ...</NuxtLayout>`

I just sent a PR for this feature.

[Adds support for folders in /layouts #5796](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/pull/5796)

Hopefully it gets accepted or at least it gives someone the idea to add this.

Answer (score 0):

Support for nested layouts is available in the latest release of Nuxt. The latest as of now is v3.10.

Read the docs here, Right below Named Layout, sorry I couldn't get the right hashtag ref for it:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts#named-layout