# Layouts inside folders Nuxt js 3

Tags: nuxtjs3

Layouts inside "layouts" folder work as expected but when I try to save a layout inside a folder like "layouts/mobile/custom.vue" does not seem to work.

just throws this message as if the layout does not exists.

```
Invalid layout `mobile/custom` selected.
```

when I try to use it inside "pages/index.vue" like this.

```
<NuxtLayout name="mobile/custom">
    some code ...
</NuxtLayout>
```

This works for "layouts/custom.vue" inside "pages/index.vue".

```
<NuxtLayout name="custom">
    some code ...
</NuxtLayout>
```

I know that Nuxt 2 added support for this after an issue, but I'm not familiarized with it as it has 1 failing check but at least says "merged".

[Adds support for folders in /layouts #1865](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/1865)

I tried to search any type of information about it but not even the documentation of Nuxt 3 itself says something related to this. Nuxt 3 Issues no luck.

[Nuxt 3 - Layouts](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts)

Does anybody knows why this happens ? or is it that this feature is not supported yet in Nuxt 3.0.0 rc4.

I tried on a clean Nuxt 3 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was added in Nuxt 2 long ago.

[Adds support for folders in /layouts #1865](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/1865)

[Nuxt.js does not respect layouts in separate folders. #1854](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1854)

It does not seem to work the same way in nuxt 3.

*update...*

I checked the source code for Nuxt 3 and definitely is not supported.

example: `layouts/folder/custom.vue`

and then use it in pages like follows

`<NuxtLayout name="folder/custom">some code ...</NuxtLayout>`

I just sent a PR for this feature.

[Adds support for folders in /layouts #5796](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/pull/5796)

Hopefully it gets accepted or at least it gives someone the idea to add this.